# Составление условия для редиректа

Tags: .htaccess

Если пользователь переходит по ссылке `m.mysite.ru/blabla/page.html`, то нужно его редиректнуть на `mysite.ru/page.html`, то есть убрать `"blabla"`, но вместо `blabla` может быть что то другое, а правило должно действовать только для `blabla`. Еcли он переходит на `m.mysite.ru/index22.html`, то редиректнет на `mysite.ru/index22.html`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать.

Comment: Непонятно, только эти два урла Вы хотите переадресовывать?

Comment: Возможно проще будет так: нужен RewriteCond в котором проверяется есть ли blabla и RewriteRule в котором убирается это blabla.

Comment: А index22? С ним как быть?

Comment: Это не обязательно, мне хотя бы ту сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тогда

```
RewriteRule ^blabla/(.+)$ /$1
```

Comment: Я понял где вы меня не поняли, часть после blabla меняется

Comment: Вопрос: Есть ли разница между (.+) и (.*)?

Comment: Поменчл. Гляньте

Comment: С плюсом - должен быть хотя бы один символ

Comment: Спасибо, работает

Comment: Если может бы только блабла без слэша поставьте вопрос после слэша

Comment: Рад был помочь. Удачи!

Comment: А если возможно mysite.ru/blabla/ без продолжения, то что делать? Знак вопроса после слеша проставить?

Comment: Лучше так. Подождите минутку я на телефоне, сейчас напишу

Comment: Хорошо, подожду

Comment: Если просто без продолжения, то замените плюс на звездочку. А если разрешаете без слэша, то возьмите слишком и следующую группу в скобки и поставьте после сколько вопрос или звездочку

Comment: Что то я не понял... Автозамена сработала?

Comment: Зараза т9 ) слишком - слэш, сколько - закрывающей скобки

Comment: Вот так? ^blabla(/(.*))?$

Comment: если заходят на /blabla/page.html, то должно остаться только page.html, а если на /blabla, то естественно ничего

Comment: Скобки только внешние, внутренние не надо

Comment: Если ссылка mysite.ru/blabla, то работает, но ссылка получается mysite.ru//, а если mysite.ru/blabla/ то не работает, в моем случае нужна работоспособность во втором варианте

Comment: `RewriteRule ^blabla(/.*)$ $1`

Comment: Такая же проблема

Comment: извиняюсь :( `RewriteRule ^blabla(/.*)*$ $1`

Comment: Все равно не поменялось :(

Comment: он сейчас должен все отправлять на корневой индекс и `blabla/` и `blabla`. нет?

Comment: я, наконец, добрался до компа и у себя проверил

Comment: почему то не работает. При этом страница mysite.ru/blabla/page.html теперь выдает 404

Comment: Я понял в чем была проблема, но вопрос двух слэшей так и остался